# How to join 2 subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to join 2 subqueries within the same table with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(phone) as users, DATE_TRUNC('month', somedate) as date_month from
(SELECT phone, MIN (created_at) as somedate
FROM analytics.orders 
where status = 'done'
GROUP BY phone) as s1
GROUP BY date_month
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT value, cohort FROM 
(SELECT SUM (amount) as value, DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) as cohort
FROM analytics.orders 
where status = 'done'
GROUP BY cohort, (SELECT SUM (amount) from analytics.orders )
ORDER BY cohort) as s2) as s3
ON s1.date_month=s3.cohort
```

But I am getting this error:

```
syntax error at or near "INNER" LINE 7: INNER JOIN ^
```

I guess that something is wrong with inner naming but I can't understand what is exactly wrong.

Comment: Your query simply makes no sense.  Delete this question.  Take some time to ask a new question.  Provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic you wan to implement.  Then include your code.

Comment: Indent your query, and you'll probably find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you actually need to join or union them.
It's all using the same table.
Rather combine the queries.

```
SELECT 
DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) as date_month,
COUNT(DISTINCT phone) as unique_phones, 
SUM(amount) as total_amount
FROM analytics.orders 
WHERE status = 'done'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)
ORDER BY 1;
```